# How to Create [Key: string] Properly in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, dynamic-properties

I want to create this as end result: `{"customerName: {"contains": "bri"}}`, but I keep getting the name of the variable written instead. I've tried a multitude of things and just can't get it to go as I want. Hoping this is simple and I'm just completely overlooking it.

```ts
interface IGraphQLFilterVariable {
  [key: string]: [key: string] | any | IGraphQLFilterVariable[]
}
let property = "customerName";
let type = "contains";
let filter = "bri";

let singleFilter: IGraphQLFilterVariable = {};
singleFilter[property] = {
  type: filter
};
console.log(singleFilter);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHEpwA4AsCKAMgGLAA2kUAanFMHAEZkoDeAUMp1wNoDWEATwBcyAM5g6IAOYBdEcj6CR4ybOQAfZHBACNaTDgIlylGnUbNuMjlwC%20Nzg%20TMwybFAD22aGF0BeZAAiBABXcQ8AW2gAOTgowIBuJxdkX29kAOCPcDhQUUTkiFcYE2gMoIY6AsLXUVApZlIKaBEMLDwiJtNaeiYUAJZbJK4xesbSqG53Lx8BGXKWNIghEuaoIacEbNEPZgA6Mg8pAAo66XG1gEphriA)

Comment: Please post your current code directly into your question body alongside the screenshot, it'll make it easier for folks to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining objects, only the *values* of the objects are expressions by default. The keys are treated as strings, so when you go `{ type: filter }`, it's essentially equivalent to `{ "type": filter }`.

To use a variable's value as a the key of an object, surround the key in brackets:

```
singleFilter[property] = { [type]: filter };
```

Your object will then look up the value of the variable `type` and use that as the key for the object.